# Internet Explorer only browser not to connect to site on local network

Tags: internet-explorer, dns, vmware, localhost, virtual-machine

I am using VMWare Fusion on my mac to test sites on a windows XP virtual machine (ie6).

My mac has the Static IP 192.168.0.220 and the site is being hosted via django, using port 8000.

Using both Bridged and NAT mode I can successfully access this site using either Chrome or Firefox (installed on the windows virtual machine) through http://192.168.0.220:8000 however ie6 just returns page not found.

- Both firewalls are disabled
- I have used `ipconfig /renew`, `/release` and `/flushdns`
- The mac can be pinged successfully from the Windows Virtual Machine
- The django site is authorised for access from any IP
- All network functionality e.g. Internet connection works fine in the VM

Are there any freaky security settings in ie6 I need to tweak to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling IE6 "Friendly Error Messages".

To disable 'friendly' error messages:

```
1. From Internet Explorer, choose "Tools" - "Options".

2. When the "Options" multi-tabbed dialog box appears, click the "Advanced" tab.

3. Underneath "Settings", scroll down to and uncheck "Show friendly HTTP error messages".

4. Click "OK" to close the dialog box.
```

Comment: You are a genius, I've been tearing my hair out with this for days. This works perfectly. When I get the rep you're getting a vote! Thanks.